# Flexigrid Table : How to add tooltip in table cell data

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, flexigrid

I have given tooltip to table header like:
By adding `if( cm.title != undefined ) {$(th).attr('title', cm.title);}`
in flexgrid.js file under the col model itreration

```
if (p.colModel) {
        thead = document.createElement("thead");
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var i = 0; i < p.colModel.length; i++) {
            var cm = p.colModel[i];
            var th = document.createElement("th");
            th.innerHTML = cm.display;
            if( cm.title != undefined ) {$(th).attr('title', cm.title);}
            if (cm.name && cm.sortable)
                $(th).attr("abbr", cm.name);
            $(th).attr("axis", "col" + i);
            if (cm.align)
                th.align = cm.align;
            if (cm.width)
                $(th).attr("width", cm.width);
            if ($(cm).attr("hide"))
                th.hidden = true;
            if (cm.process)
                th.process = cm.process;
            $(tr).append(th)
        }
        $(thead).append(tr);
        $(t).prepend(thead)
    }
```

And Use Like :

```
colModel : [
                { display: 'Tender No', title: 'tbgNo', name : 'tbgNo', width : 200, sortable : true, align: 'left',}
```

So, How can we add tooltip to Table cell./

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.setAttribute("title","message tool-tip you want");`

Answer (score 0):

Hello after R & D lots I found one best result which are working in all situation.
We can give tooltip to flexgrid cell by using span title at where we populate the grid
Please look into this code.

```
if(!(jsonobj ==null)){
                for(var i=0; i < jsonobj.list.length; i++){
                rows.push({  cell: 
                    [
                     "<span title='"+jsonobj.list[i].tbgNo+"'>"+checkforUndefined(jsonobj.list[i].tbgNo)+"</span>",
                     "<span title='"+jsonobj.list[i].title+"'>"+"<A HREF=javascript:showCodes("
                        + jsonobj.list[i].id
                        + ")>"
                        + jsonobj.list[i].title
                        + "</A> "+"</span>",
                        checkforUndefined(jsonobj.list[i].startDate)
                    ] 
                });
                }
```

Thanks..